# What is the default max post content size in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, post, http-post

I am using Spring Boot application. When I do post request as below, I can able to pass content size of 5MB. As per the documentation here, default is 2MB. Let me the default size of post content.

Following are the specifications:

1. Tomcat server (Default)
2. WebMVC
3. Embedded container

**Request url:** `http://localhost:8080/store`

**Request body:**

```
{
  "value": "test...." (length=5MB)
}
```

Comment: There is too little information here. We need information on your architecture (WebMVC or WebFlux), which container is used (Tomcat, Jetty, .... ), how are you running this (embedded container or deployed to an external container). Please provide additional information.

Comment: @M.Deinum Update the specifications.

Comment: I have update it. Its Tomcat. I am passing random alphanumeric of length (5000000) in the value field. I see max size is set as 2MB by default. Refer https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.server.server.tomcat.max-http-form-post-size

Comment: The max size is for form content, you aren't sending form content but a body.

Comment: Okay. Then What will be max size for request body?

Comment: afaik there isn't.

Comment: See also https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/18521 about the confusion on what this property does.

Answer (score 0):

As [this ticket](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/18521) shows there was/is some confusion on what the [`server.tomcat.max-http-form-post-size`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.server.server.tomcat.max-http-form-post-size) actually does. (Actually the previous naming but it provides some additional context!).

But in short it sets the maximum size of the request parameters for a POST request. Those parameters are only available for a form that is being submitted through POST. It doesn't apply to a JSON body being sent as the body of a request.

When using a multipart request you could limit this with the `spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size` property, however this would require a multipart request instead of a simple `application/json` with a post.

For, at least, Tomcat there is no unified way of setting the maximum size of a request that is going to be accepted. However you could implement this yourself using a servlet filter and check the size (if available!) and either allow/disallow the processing.