How to restrict POST request payload size in Spring Boot to 1MB or 2MB?
I have a Spring Boot application with a POST API endpoint that processes large payloads. By default, I understand that Spring Boot (with embedded Tomcat) sets the maximum HTTP POST request size to 2MB using the property server.tomcat.max-http-post-size=2MB.
However, when I test my API with payloads larger than 2MB, such as 50MB, the API processes these requests without throwing any errors. I need to restrict the payload size to a maximum of 1MB or 2MB to prevent processing very large requests.I am using spring boot version 3.0.5
Here are my current configurations in application.properties:
server.tomcat.max-http-post-size=2MB

Issues:
Why am I able to process large payloads despite setting server.tomcat.max-http-post-size=2MB?
How can I ensure that my Spring Boot application throws an error when the payload exceeds 1MB or 2MB?

If you are sending POST request as Multipart. Like a file upload. These settings will work:
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=2MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=2MB

If you are sending a form request with parameters then this setting will work for Tomcat:
server.tomcat.max-http-post-size=2MB

If you are sending a huge JSON payload with a POST request there is no unified way of setting the maximum size of a request that is going to be accepted. However you could implement this yourself using a servlet filter and check the size (if available!) and either allow/disallow the processing.
Based on this answer by M. Deinum: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73686336/14294053

i am hitting simple request via post man with json payload
